# Flattening a nested JSON object in Azure Data Factory with dynamic schema

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, transform

I am trying to use Azure Data Factory to move the keys/values of one, and always one and always named the same, nested JSON object and copy them to the root level of the JSON. However, I do not know the exact keys of this nested object. Please forgive me if I am using the wrong terms here, but I will show what I mean:

Example 1:

```
{
  "nestedObject":{"key1":"value1"},
  "boolean": true,
}
```

Should result in:

```
  {
  "key1":"value1",
  "boolean": true,
 }
```

Example 2:

```
  {
  "nestedObject": {"key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},
  "boolean": true,
}
```

Should result in:

```
{
  "key2":"value2",
  "key3":"value3",
  "boolean": true,
}
```

These are just two simple examples, however, there are an unknown number of variations of the «nestedObject». The rest of the object is always the same ("boolean": true) and I need to keep all existing key/value pairs at the root level.

I have tried a few things with the Data Flow activity and by reading about the available [transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-transformation-overview) it seems like it should be doable, but I cannot quite make it work dynamically.

Is what I am trying to do possible by using the data flow activity?

Comment: So, the name `nestedObject` would be same for all the data?

Comment: That is correct:)

Answer (score 1):

- Since the column name `nestedObject` does not change, you can use select transformation to achieve your requirement.
- The following is the data preview of my source.

[image]

- Now, in select transformation, remove the mapping for `nestedObject` and use it as shown in the below image. Create a rule-based mapping with condition as `true()`, name as `$$` and specify the hierarchical level as `nestedObject`. The below is an image for reference.

[image]

- This would give the result as shown in the below image:

[image]